# Undefined Reference во время линковки проекта с GStreamer

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer

У меня есть очень простой проект с GStreamer:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    GstElement *pipeline = nullptr;
    GstBus *bus = nullptr;
    GstMessage *msg = nullptr;

    // gstreamer initialization
    gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);
    
}
```

Я хочу собрать его с таким CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Mgm)
find_package(PkgConfig)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)

#including GStreamer header files directory
include_directories(
        ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#linking GStreamer library directory
link_directories(
        ${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_executable(mgm src/main.cpp)
```

Проблема в том, что при сборке я получаю ошибку линковщика:

```
[keddad@priest mgm]$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/keddad/Documents/mgm
[keddad@priest mgm]$ make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable mgm
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mgm.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `gst_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mgm.dir/build.make:103: mgm] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/mgm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

В системе установлен пакет [gstreamer](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gstreamer/), так что библиотеки для линковки, кажется, должны присутствовать. При этом в IDE (VS Code) я мог я вижу сигнатуры функций и могу, например, перейти к определению структуры из gst - следственно, он точно нормально установлен и находится системой. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно просто не хватает указания, что цель надо линковать с указанными библиотеками:

```
target_link_libraries(mgm ${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES})
```